# Undo cell selection when entering a formula

Tags: google-sheets

Sometimes when I'm working on a formula I accidentally select a cell I don't want to. These are some strategies I've used:

- find the cell in the formula and manually delete it
- press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to undo

Is there any way to "undo the last added cell" while editing a formula?

Comment: Did you tried to press the back/suppress key?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the mouse to select a cell (or multiple cells) while building a formula, you can simply re-select the cell you want.

In other words, while building a formula, you click on B4 but you meant to click on B5. Just click on B5 before moving on.